# uWSGI as a standalone http server with lua

Tags: lua, uwsgi

I'm trying to set up uWSGI to run as a standalone server running a simple LUA script(right now, as a POC, using the hello world from http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Lua.html).

Here's my uwsgi.ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
master = true
workers = 1
threads = 8
listen = 4096
max-request = 512
pidfile = /uwsgi/logs/uwsgi.pid
procname-master = uWSGI master
auto-procname = true
lua = /uwsgi/hello.lua
socket-timeout = 30
socket = /uwsgi/uwsgi_1.sock
http = 127.0.0.1:80
http-to = /uwsgi/uwsgi_1.sock
```

When sending a web request, an empty response is received, and uWSGI process outputs:

```
-- unavailable modifier requested: 0 --
```

I've read this usually means a plugin is missing, however, LUA plugin is installed, and when doing the same but through NGINX everything works fine, which means there's no problem loading LUA.

Any help please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody told me I had to add `http-modifier1 = 6` and now it works.
Still don't understand what does '6' mean, but whatever.

Comment: a little google-fu produced [this link](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/QuickstartRack), which explains what that means. and [this link](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Protocol.html), which lists some of the various values and what they map to.